# Strange occurrences with controlling multiple keys being held down

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, keyup, keymapping

With the below code, when a key is pressed its keycode is pushed to the keymap array if it's not already there and when a key is let up its keycode is taken out of the array. When testing this out by constantly shoving the keymap array to the console, I found some strange things.

```
var keymap = [];

$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if($.inArray(e.keyCode,keymap) == -1) {keymap.push(e.keyCode);}
});

$(window).keyup(function(e) {
    for(i = 0;i < keymap.length;i++) {
        if(keymap[i] = e.keyCode) {keymap.splice(i,1);}
    }
});

setInterval(function() {console.log(keymap);},100);
```

1. If I hold down a and d at the same time their keycodes are present in keymap, then if I hold down w all three of their keycodes are present. Now when I let go of w it's removed from the array, but so is d even though I'm still holding down d.
2. I then found that I can hold down a, w, and d and they'll all be put into keymap, but it will not put w, a, and s in keymap when I hold them down. A combination of two of these will be put in, but the third will not.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: In keyup `if(keymap[i] = e.keyCode)` should be `if(keymap[i] == e.keyCode)`.

Comment: where is keymap defined? and you should use `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode`, but not critical

Comment: @zgr024 Sorry I left out the declaration, edited it in

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KVr7c/  it works... just change the interval to what you want... I thought 100ms was a bit fast... but as Yograj suggested, you were missing the ==

Comment: @zgr024 It doesn't work for me in the fiddle, the same anomalies happen, could it be a hardware problem? What browser are you using, as I'm using Chrome.

Comment: I am using chrome... please be more specific about the anomolies

Comment: @zgr024 Yes I just tested it in firefox and they still happen, the two anomalies I mentioned in the question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35531/discussion-between-zgr024-and-cains)

Comment: During the discussion, we found that after the few fixed mentioned below, Cains was running into a hardware issue with his keyboard that would not register more than a couple keys pressed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison is an assignment actually. Change `if(keymap[i] = e.keyCode)` to

```
if (keymap[i] == e.keyCode)
//             ^
```

Also, you should use local variables:

```
for(var i = 0; …
//  ^^^
```

And while it shouldn't matter for your array where items are supposed to be unique, you need to decrease the counter variable `i` after you remove an item or you skip to check the next one otherwise:

```
keymap.splice(i--,1)
//             ^^
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't fix my problem

Comment: I came to the same conclusions that Bergi did, but took longer.  Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JBUEv/

Comment: @Cains: Then do some logging of the `e.keycode` in the event handlers to see whether they are firing wrong, whether your add/remove code doesn't work (which my answer corrects), or whether something else messes around with your `keymap` array.